# Problem using Java with ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

```
 try {
        //providing path of jrxml to java
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ReportTemplates/WeeklyReportForCurrentWeek.jrxml");
        JasperDesign jdesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign(inputStream);

        String imgPath = "C:/Users/Sorathiya.Deven/";
        //Compile managaer

        JasperReport jreport = JasperManager.compileReport(jdesign);
        //Run time Report parameters
        Map param = new HashMap();
        param.put("CurrWeek", new java.math.BigDecimal(week));
        param.put("CurrYear", new java.math.BigDecimal(year));
        param.put("imgPath", imgPath);

        //Fatch Database
        Connection con = CreateConnection.makeConnection();
        //compile report
        JasperPrint jprint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, param, con);

        JRPdfExporter exporterPDF = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporterPDF.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jprint);
        exporterPDF.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "C:/Users/Sorathiya.Deven/WeeklyReportForCurrentWeek.pdf");
        exporterPDF.exportReport();
        CreateConnection.closeConnection(con);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hello friends i am using above given code for showing my report containing sub report but when i run this i get report containing blank page does any one tell me whats the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is empty.
Please parse sql query then create the report.